# C pointer based growable stack

Tags: c, stack, pointers

This is my first attempt at writing a C program, it a generic stack that can grow accordingly. It appears to work correctly, however I am worried that is just a fluke and I could be doing something very wrong.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback/criticism.

I am aware I should split this out into a .h and .c file but for demonstration purposes I have listed it as one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct Stack
{
    void** data;
    int capacity;
    int count;
} Stack;

void stack_init(Stack *stack, int capacity)
{
    stack->data = (void**)malloc(capacity * sizeof(void*));
    stack->capacity = capacity;
    stack->count = 0;
}

void stack_push(Stack *stack, void* entry)
{
    if (stack->count >= stack->capacity)
    {
        stack->capacity *= 2;
        stack->data = (void**)realloc(stack->data, stack->capacity * sizeof(void*));
    }

    stack->data[stack->count] = entry;
    stack->count++;
}

void* stack_pop(Stack *stack)
{
    stack->count--;
    return stack->data[stack->count];
}

bool stack_is_empty(Stack *stack)
{
    return (stack->count == 0);
}

int main()
{
    Stack myStack;

    stack_init(&myStack, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        stack_push(&myStack, i);
    }

    while (!stack_is_empty(&myStack))
    {
        printf("%d\n", (int)stack_pop(&myStack));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the warnings [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VP6ylzPS9uruZFSp). Passing integers around as casted pointers is probably not what you want there.

Comment: Hint: If you'll try this with other data types like `double` or any kind of `struct` this code will fail spectacularly.. What you're doing is wrong. `void*` looses any type information, including the size of the original type. Thus `sizeof(void*)` for allocation is futile from the beginning. You're allocating space for a pointer size.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guess OP is reusing the `void*` space to store an `int` under the assumption that `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(void*)`. The practice of (ab)using the generic `void*` data itself to store the value instead of pointing to an external data block (and thus worrying about lifetime) is common in C.

Comment: @L.F. I guess that the OP tries to store generic data types in the stack, and fundamentally failed to do that correctly. _"store the value instead of pointing to an external data block (and thus worrying about lifetime) is common in C."_ That's not necessary if you want to handle `int` values only, and makes the stack interface quite confusing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's what C libraries (even some C++ ones) usually do anyway - providing a `void*` slot to store data, and allowing the user to use it the way they like. Not really confusing IMO, as long as the user uses the slot in a consistent way. The C-style generic programming is quite different from the way we usually think in C++, but I don't think it's problematic to stick to C practices in C code :)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest that you do more error checking:

- `malloc` or `realloc` may fail.
- I can initialize the stack with negative capacity.
- I can pop more elements than I pushed.

In all these cases, your implementation silently swallows the errors and accesses invalid addresses.

As [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52802) said in comments, if you want to store generic elements that exceed `void*` in size, you need to allocate memory for them and let the `void*` point to them, e.g.:

```
typedef struct {
    // ...
} BigStruct;

// pushing
BigStruct* data = malloc(sizeof(BigStruct));
// initialize *data
stack_push(&stack, data);

// popping
BigStruct* data = stack_pop(&stack);
// use *data
free(data);
```

Some small issues:

- It is not common to cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc` in C.
- If the stack is initialized to capacity 0, then the stack will never grow and elements will be stored at invalid positions.  A solution is to adjust the capacity to 1 automatically.

Answer (score 8):

There are two main problems with the code that must be addressed:

- You store *pointers to data* in an array, rather than actual data. This is not useful, since pointers may point to data that goes out of scope or otherwise becomes obsolete. When writing a container class such as a stack/LIFO, one should store so-called "hard copies" of the data passed.
- The code is not valid C. You implicitly convert from an `int` which is data, to a `void*` which is a pointer. Details here: [“Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast” issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues). To prevent non-C from compiling without errors then set gcc/clang/icc to always compile with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

  Apart from the implicit conversion itself being invalid, there is no guarantee that you can safely convert from `int` to `void*` and back even if you use a cast. This conversion relies on poorly specified behavior.

Because of these two remarks, the code cannot be fixed, it must be rewritten from scratch. To rewrite this into a proper stack container, it must be rewritten to use bytes of raw data (`uint8_t`) and make hard copies of the data passed.

---

Other remarks:

- When popping from the stack, check `count` to see if there actually are any items left!
- `typedef struct Stack { ... } Stack;` The "struct tag in this case is superfluous, you can just write `typedef struct { ... } Stack;`.
- `int main()` is an obsolete form of main() declaration, always use `int main (void)` instead (or the version with argv+argc).
- You don't use *const correctness*. Functions that do not change the passed `Stack*` should `const` qualify it: `bool stack_is_empty(const Stack *stack)`.
- When storing the size of an array, the integer type `size_t` is more correct to use than `int`, since `int` may not be large enough and in addition it is signed.
- `return (stack->count == 0);` No parenthesis needed here, it's just clutter.
- `(void**)malloc` etc. No cast needed here, it's just clutter.
- When calling malloc and realloc, always check if they succeeded by checking the result against NULL. 
  -Calling realloc repeatedly like this is inefficient. That's why a stack is usually implemented as a double linked linked list. You may not have learnt about these yet, but they are the most suitable way to implement containers that often add/remove items at the top or bottom, at the case of slower access time for items located at a random place inside the container. You will not use this stack like that, so a linked list would be more suitable.

Comment: "Calling realloc repeatedly like this is very inefficient. That's why a stack is usually implemented as a double linked linked list. You may not have learnt about these yet, but they are the most suitable way to implement containers that often add/remove items at the top or bottom."  Hmm ... C++ vectors do this, and usually outperform linked lists.  Am I missing something special about `realloc`?

Comment: C++ vectors *usually* outperform linked lists, but it does depend on the access patterns.  I expect the optimum data structure for a stack is more like a *rope*: a linked list of chunks; each chunk big enough to accommodate a decent number of items.  No reallocation, but very few allocations, and very little pointer chaining.

Comment: @L.F. `realloc` or heap allocation in general is slow. Therefore, the implementation of std::vector uses an allocation scheme along the lines of: "allocate align * n bytes upon creation, when running out of memory reallocate align * 2n", doubling the size each time. This reduces the amount of calls. Similar algorithms are often used in C too when designing a string ADT or whatever. Of course a std::vector or any array outperforms a linked list in _access time_, since it has random access. Arrays vs linked lists is very basic computer science stuff.

Comment: Isn't OP doing what you are describing? `stack->capacity *= 2;`  Also don't forget that linked lists have space implications.

Comment: @L.F. Oh, they are, actually. I should remove that remark then. Regardless, a linked list would be faster for lots of pushing/popping.

Comment: @Lundin Wouldn't linked list perform even worse for lots of pushing and popping, since you need to allocate memory from heap for every push, even if you are not reaching a new maximum size?

Comment: @Lundin, remember that this is a *stack*, so all accesses are to the top of stack, and the penalty for "access an arbitrary element" isn't ever paid.  Many small allocations is still a performance hit, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Ease of clean-up**

Consider a function to empty a `Stack` and free its allocated memory.

```
void stack_clean_up(Stack *stack) {
  free(stack->data);
  stack->data = NULL;
  stack->capacity = 0;
  stack->count = 0;
}


int foo() {
  Stack myStack;
  ....
  // Preceding code all done, time to clean up
  stack_clean_up(&myStack);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, on my second revision I did add one like this. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238380/c-pointer-based-growable-stack-rev2