# C pointer based growable stack rev2

Tags: c, stack, pointers

**Following on from my previous question:** [C pointer based growable stack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/238338)

I have made some improvements (*hopefully!*) based on the very helpful comments and suggestions.
I have checked that the stack can push and pop doubles now, so hopefully it will also be OK with structs.

I have a could of questions regarding the changes I have made:

1. I noticed `memcpy()` didn't work with `void *` so I switched to using `uin8_t`; is that recommended/necessary or could I have cast to `uint8_t` for `memcpy()`? Not sure which approach is the best...
2. How should a failed `malloc()`/`realloc()` be handled? Return an error code? Exit? Return NULL?

Again, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions/criticism:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ITEMS 16

typedef struct {
    uint8_t *data;
    size_t itemSize;
    unsigned count;
    unsigned capacity;
} Stack;

void stack_init(Stack *stack, size_t itemSize, unsigned capacity);
bool stack_is_empty(const Stack *stack);
void stack_push(Stack *stack, void *item);
void* stack_pop(Stack *stack);
void stack_destroy(Stack *stack);

void stack_init(Stack *stack, size_t itemSize, unsigned capacity)
{
    unsigned initialCapacity = capacity == 0 ? 1 : capacity;
    size_t size = initialCapacity * itemSize;

    stack->count = 0;
    stack->capacity = initialCapacity;
    stack->itemSize = itemSize;
    stack->data = (uint8_t *)malloc(size);

    if (stack->data == NULL)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    memset(stack->data, 0, size);
}

bool stack_is_empty(const Stack *stack)
{
    return stack->count == 0;
}

void stack_push(Stack *stack, void *item)
{
    if (stack->count >= stack->capacity)
    {
        stack->capacity *= 2;
        stack->data = (uint8_t *)realloc(stack->data, stack->capacity * stack->itemSize);

        if (stack->data == NULL)
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }

    unsigned offset = stack->count * stack->itemSize;
    memcpy(stack->data + offset, item, stack->itemSize);
    stack->count++;
}

void* stack_pop(Stack *stack)
{
    if (stack_is_empty(stack) == true)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    uint8_t *item = (uint8_t *)malloc(stack->itemSize);

    if (item == NULL)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    stack->count--;
    unsigned offset = stack->count * stack->itemSize;
    memcpy(item, stack->data + offset, stack->itemSize);

    return (void *)item;
}

void stack_destroy(Stack *stack)
{
    free(stack->data);
    stack->count = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    Stack stack;
    stack_init(&stack, sizeof(int), 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        stack_push(&stack, (void *)&i);
    }

    while (!stack_is_empty(&stack))
    {
        int value;
        value = *((int *)stack_pop(&stack));
        printf("%d\n", value);
    }

    stack_destroy(&stack);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
>     stack->data = (uint8_t *)realloc(stack->data, stack->capacity * stack->itemSize);
> ```

This is wrong, because if `realloc()` failed, then there's now no way to access the memory previously pointed to by `stack->data`.  The correct pattern for `realloc()` is:

```
void *newData = realloc(stack->data, stack->capacity * stack->itemSize);
if (!newData) {
    // Insert error handling - you'll want to restore the old stack->capacity here
    // or (better) wait until we're okay before updating.
    return FAILURE:
}
stack->data = newData;
```

---

I recommend against casting the result of `malloc()` family when assigning - these functions return `void*`, which is assignable to any pointer type without a cast.  The unnecessary cast just distracts the reader (because casts generally indicate danger areas in code).  The same is true for conversions from pointer types to `void*`, such as this one:

> ```
> return (void *)item;
> ```

That can simply be

```
return item;
```

---

The `stack_pop` interface is difficult to use - callers have to deal with possible null pointer return, and must remember to `free()` the result.  Instead, consider having the caller provide memory to write into:

```
void stack_pop(Stack *stack, void *target);
```

The caller should already know the size required for `target`, and can now get  results in local (`auto`) storage:

```
int foo;
stack_pop(&stack, &foo);
// no need to check for null, or to call free()
```